# How to convert given formula to VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, date

I got a formula from Ron Ronsfield's answer to ["In excel, date shows as mdyyyy, want as mm-dd-yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895956/in-excel-date-shows-as-mdyyyy-want-as-mm-dd-yyyy)

The formula is:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"00\/00\/0000")
```

I was able to [bodge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bodge) this formula into the following code for my macro:

```
a = 1
    While Range("A" & a) <> ""
        Range("M" & a) = "=--TEXT(" & Range("H" & a) & ",""00\/00\/0000"")"

        a = a + 1
    Wend
```

I have tried a couple of ways to get this into a code that just prints an answer to my excel, and doesn't insert a formula, but to know avail.

I was wondering if anybody had a suggestion on how to get this into a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent which places the date values directly in column `M` instead of the formulas would be:

```
a = 1
While Range("A" & a) <> ""
    'Range("M" & a) = "=--TEXT(" & Range("H" & a) & ",""00\/00\/0000"")"
    Range("M" & a) = CDate(Format(Range("H" & a), "00\/00\/0000"))

    a = a + 1
Wend
```